# Using amCharts "Amcharts.loadfile" dataloader to pull chart data from multiple CSV files

Tags: amcharts

I have searched high and low for a solution and have found many people asking this question but no answer. I am trying to alter this example to work with external data: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/making-stock-charts-period-selector-input-fields-read-only/

**Is it possible to load data from multiple CSVs into an array and then apply each set to a chart dataset??** It's possible that this code does work but it is hung up on something else.

I am getting console errors:

`GET http://www.example.com/1 404 (Not found) dataloader.min.js 1`

`GET http://www.example.com/2 404 (Not found) dataloader.min.js 1`

`GET http://www.example.com/0 404 (Not found) dataloader.min.js 1`

`GET http://www.example.com/3 404 (Not found) dataloader.min.js 1`

Thanks!

Something like this...

```
var dataSets = [];
var files = ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv', '4.csv'];

for(var fileid in files) {
    AmCharts.loadFile(fileid, {}, function(    response ) {

        /**
        * Parse CSV
        */
 var data = AmCharts.parseCSV( response, {
    "useColumnNames": true
    } );
 dataSets.push(data);
 });
}
```

(Not sure whether to use "dataLoader" or "dataProvider")

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
type: "stock",
"theme": "none",
//"dataProvider": dataSets,

pathToImages: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",

   dataSets: [{
   title: "first data set",
   fieldMappings: [{
   fromField: "value",
   toField: "value"
   }, {
   fromField: "rank",
   toField: "rank"
   }],
   dataLoader: dataSets[0],
   categoryField: "date"
   },

 {
  title: "second data set",
  fieldMappings: [{
  fromField: "value",
  toField: "value"
 }, {
  fromField: "rank",
  toField: "rank"
  }],
dataLoader: dataSets[1],
categoryField: "date"
},

{
  title: "third data set",
  fieldMappings: [{
  fromField: "value",
  toField: "value"
}, {
  fromField: "rank",
  toField: "rank"
}],
dataLoader: dataSets[2],
categoryField: "date"
},

{
  title: "fourth data set",
  fieldMappings: [{
  fromField: "value",
  toField: "value"
}, {
  fromField: "rank",
  toField: "rank"
}],
 dataLoader: dataSets[3],
 categoryField: "date"
}

],
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your `for in` loop is wrong. The `fileid` variable is the index of the array, which is why you were getting 0, 1, 2, and 3. Consider using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead, which has the logic you were looking for.

In any case, you don't want to use the loadFile method as you can specify the dataLoader in each dataSet in the stock chart, similar to how each dataSet has its own `dataProvider`, e.g.:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  dataSets: [{
     // ...
     dataLoader: {
       url: "/path/to/csvfile",
       format: "csv",
       useColumnNames: true
     },
     // ...
  },
  // repeat for each dataSet as needed
  ]
});
```

You can find documentation on how to use the dataLoader in [its github repository](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader).

In your case, your makeChart call would look similar to this:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "stock",
  "theme": "none",

  pathToImages: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",

  dataSets: [{
      title: "first data set",
      fieldMappings: [{
        fromField: "value",
        toField: "value"
      }, {
        fromField: "rank",
        toField: "rank"
      }],
      dataLoader: {
        url: "/path/to/1.csv",
        format: "csv",
        useColumnNames: true
      },
      categoryField: "date"
    },

    {
      title: "second data set",
      fieldMappings: [{
        fromField: "value",
        toField: "value"
      }, {
        fromField: "rank",
        toField: "rank"
      }],
      dataLoader: {
        url: "/path/to/2.csv",
        format: "csv",
        useColumnNames: true
      }
      categoryField: "date"
    },

    {
      title: "third data set",
      fieldMappings: [{
        fromField: "value",
        toField: "value"
      }, {
        fromField: "rank",
        toField: "rank"
      }],
      dataLoader: {
        url: "/path/to/3.csv",
        format: "csv",
        useColumnNames: true
      },
      categoryField: "date"
    },

    {
      title: "fourth data set",
      fieldMappings: [{
        fromField: "value",
        toField: "value"
      }, {
        fromField: "rank",
        toField: "rank"
      }],
      dataLoader: {
        url: "/path/to/4.csv",
        format: "csv",
        useColumnNames: true
      },
      categoryField: "date"
    }

  ],
  // ...
});
```

Note that `useColumnNames` will take the name of the columns in the first row and use them as it populates the dataProvider array in each dataSet. Make sure you have a header row with `date`, `rank`, and `value` in your files.

Comment: Thank you! That took care of those errors and each dataset now loads as it should when selected in the dropdown :D

Comment: When the compared dataset is selected there are other errors. Where can I find what these errors mean?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueAxisAuto0_1501114660773' of undefined
    at b.parseGraphData (amcharts.js:296)
    at b.parsePartSerialData (amcharts.js:295)
    at b.parseSerialData (amcharts.js:291)
    at b.parseData (serial.js:43)
    at b.initChart (serial.js:25)
    at b.initChart (amstock.js:74)
    at b.validateData (amcharts.js:136)
    at b.validateData (serial.js:29)
    at b.zoomChart (amstock.js:45)
    at b.updatePanelsWithNewData (amstock.js:32)

Comment: We don't have a list of errors or exceptions, but there might be an issue with your csv files. Can you post a link to your chart somewhere or pastebin your csv files so I can reproduce this and help troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is from server caching? I don't see that the new files load, even when I clear browser cache. I need it to always pull the newest version of the file... I will post full current code below. Thank you SO much for all your help!!!

Comment: It's a possibility. I'm not seeing any issues when I run your code [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/7ef5999d083a883309a2eddf80a91fd6?editors=0010) with your data. Note that you don't need `skip` when you have `useColumnNames` set to true. This will cause the dataloader to skip the first row after the header, which you don't want.

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate all your help! :)